# three.js sphere stops rotating when changing material color

Tags: colors, three.js, geometry

Please open this link:

http://miloud.webs.com/me/index.html

You can see a cube rotating on a space. You can change the texture and color of the cube from the Controls -> Geometry on the link. When I use a sphere instead of the cube, everything works fine except when I change the sphere color (from Controls -> Gemoetry, on the link), the sphere stops rotating. When I select an image for the sphere texture, it rotates fine again. The only deference in the code is, instead of :

geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 200, 200, 200 );

I use:

geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(75, 32, 32);

Answer (score 0):

The sphere actually does not stop rotating. I was deceived by the fact that the sphere most of the time looks the same, so at the first glance it appeared as not rotating, but it does rotate.